# What method or set of methods should be used to detect similar objects on a picture/video?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition

At the moment I use Caffe to recognize the objects on the picture.
There can be several hundreds of objects and many of them can be very similar (like a bolt with square head and a bolt with 6-sided head).
In addition to the photo of the object, it is possible to take several photos of the objects from different angles or shoot a video.
Is it possible to increase the accuracy of recognition, in addition to comparing the results of the photos of the same scene from different angles?

*Updated:*

## Learned model setup

I created a 3D model for every object. The synthetic training images were rendered in Blender. The various rendering parameters were used: camera’s location, lights's position, light's intensity, 3 textures (white, gray, dark gray) for the ground and 4 textures for the objects (light green, green, dark green, almost black green).
*Because objects can have different colors, I decided to use grayvalue images to save time and the size of the input data and not to render same set of images for every possible color.*
The models were rendered at a resolution of 256x256 pixels, 5000 renders for every model. I use OpenCV to segmentate the image and detect the objects' locations. That is why green materials with different tones were used. Renders were segmentated, substracted images were resized to 256x256 images and converted to grayvalue images.
I used "AlexNet" network to learn the model. It is always 100% accuracy during validation(10-20% of training images) after 3-4 epochs.
Ussualy there are many objects on a real photo. It is segmented using the same algorithm as was applied to the rendered images. Recognition is performed for every segmented "subimage".

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? It is always possible to increase the accuracy of the recognition by feeding more data into the algorithm you train, the question is too broad

Comment: The problem is that often one object recognized as another (very similar looking object) and, of course, I want somehow to increase the accuracy. Isn't that clear?! Most  Probably just CNN is not enougth for such task or I can do something with input images? I think, this question is for people who has already faced a similar problem.  
  
_Next are just my thoughts._
  
I noticed that even for a human it is not always possible to recognize an object from a single image. In real life we are rotating the object, looking from different angles...

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you have already tried. In general the issue you describe has tons of solutions, parts of them discussed in machine learning courses and other part - in research papers. Right now question seems too broad - we don't even know your architecture or training results (if your model fails to achieve good performance only on CV or test set, or it poorly performs even on training set). Please add more information and what you tried, which outcome you get so that we can help

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. This is my first question on forum. I edited the question. Hope this helps.